# IPE app not opening in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, updates, icons, snap, vector-drawings

I have just installed Ipe extensible drawing editor app (version 7.2.6). My Ubuntu version is 20.04. There is an app icon but when I click on it, the app simply does not open. Is there any way to fix this?